# Is My CakePHP BelongsTo Relationship Creating Blank Entries?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, relationship, belongs-to

I have two database tables, Homes and Assets, with a HasMany-BelongsTo relationship.

Until recently, every Asset belonged to one Home.  This has become more complex recently: now some Assets belong to a Realtor or a Region instead of a Home.

Today I've been seeing dozens of blank entries appearing in my Homes table.  It seems almost certain that they're the result of new Assets, that are unconnected to a Home, being saved.

Is it likely that the BelongsTo Home relationship in the Asset model is forcing the creation of these blank entries?  (Or is there another probable reason?)  If it is the relationship, is there a quick way of modifying the relationship so the generation of an Asset can, but doesn't necessary have to, go hand-in-hand with generating a new Home entry?

**EDITED**: Here are the current relationships between the models:

Asset:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
   'Home' =>array('className' => 'Home', 'foreignKey' => 'home_num'));

var $hasOne = array(
   'Landmark' =>array('className' => 'Landmark', 'foreignKey' => 'asset_num',
              'dependent' => true ));
```

Home:

```
var $hasOne = array('HighlightImage' => array(
    'className'     => 'Asset',
    'conditions'    => 'highlight_image = TRUE',
    'order'         => '',
    'foreignKey'    => 'home_num',
    'dependent'     => false,
    'exclusive'     => false,
    'finderQuery'   => ''));

var $hasMany = array('Assets' => array(
    'className'     => 'Asset',
    'conditions'    => '',
    'order'         => '(Assets.title + 0 ) ASC',
    'limit'         => '200',
    'foreignKey'    => 'home_num',
    'dependent'     => false,
    'exclusive'     => false,
    'finderQuery'   => ''));
```

Landmark:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Assets' => array(
        'className' => 'Asset',
        'foreignKey' => 'asset_num'),
'Regions' =>array(
        'className' => 'Region',
        'foreignKey' => 'region_num'));
```

Region:

```
var $hasMany = array('Landmarks' => array(
     'className' => 'Landmark',
     'foreignKey' => 'region_num'));
```

Comment: You have incorrect relationships, post your relation codes into the post.

Comment: @Ish Kumar: edited with the model relationships.  Pretty sure they're suboptimal - any help you can give me to locate the specific culprit for my problem would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have what is know as an ARC relationship. This means you have one asset table that has multiple relationships. As you describe above, it seems that now the Assets table will contain data that can belong to 3 different tables: Homes, Realtors, or Regions. In my experience, cake does not handle ARC relationships very well.

My advice is to create multiple asset tables:

```
home_assets
realtor_assets
region_assets
```

At first glance, you may think this is over kill. However, in terms of simplicity, this is the best way to do it.

You can use a single table, but it requires a little more work. If you really want to use a single asset table, you will need to add an additional column (type) if you haven't already. Then you will need to add the type to the asset before each save, depending on what is saving the data: home, realtor, or region.

If you provide a sample of the code you are using (for home, realtor, and region) as it applies to assets, it would be easier to diagnose. Consider using pastebin.com as I assume the code set may be rather large.

Comment: Oh, the relationships are a mess (in my defence, a lot of them were in place before I came along!)  The assets table has home_num, realtor_num and kiosk_num fields - two of which will be 0 for any given asset - to specify ownership.  In a completely different way of doing things, each asset also HasOne "Landmark" which BelongsTo a Region (which HasMany Landmarks).   Perhaps a Landmark should Have One asset, rather than the other way around?  The prospect of refactoring it all is quite intimidating.  I'll update the question with the model relationships in any case...